# Why is onActivityResult() Intent data equal null?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am getting `Intent data = null`and  i don't understand why? i am using an 
intent  from an `Activity B`(`A to B: using an intent too (startActivity())`) like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
          File image = null;
           try {
               image = saveImageFile();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
            if (image != null) {
               intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image ));
               startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot take a picture!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and from my`onActivityResult`i tried this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras == null) {
                    return;
                }
                Bitmap myImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                scaleMyImage(myImageBitmap); 
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }
    }
```

I am saving the picture here: `File storageDirec = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`. From debug i am getting correct params(`requestCode = 1 & resultCode = -1`), but `data = null`? - Can somebody tell/help me why the Intent data is null? - Thanks, Carl